# Conditional query based on aggregation fields

Tags: laravel

Given I have this simple query:

```
$builder = User::select(DB::raw('users.age as age, users.restrict as restrict'))
               ->whereBetween("user.id",$id)
               ->get();
```

Is there any way to get users where `age` is lower than `restrict` column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both `age` and `restrict` are columns, use the `whereColumn()` method. Also, it looks like you want to get only records with IDs that are in `$ids` array. So, use `whereIn()`:

```
User::whereColumn('age', '<', 'restrict')->whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This `->where("user_id", $id)` returns only one user! does not it ?

```
$users = DB::table('users')->whereBetween("id",$ids)
                           ->where("age",'<','restrict')->get();
```

Or

```
$users = User::where("age",'<','restrict')->whereBetween("id",$ids)->get();
```

Comment: my bad that should be whereBetween some array of id's, I tried that unknown column